# Wordpress site redirection

Tags: wordpress, networking

I have build a site using subdomain in.itz4u.in in wordpress. Now if people search itz4u or type URL itz4u then automatically they should come to in.itz4u.in

Pl let me know how can i achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Are the domain and subdomain pointing to the same host?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a 301 redirect. You can use the web server configuration file .htaccess.

Please keep in mind that a small mistake in your .htaccess code can make your WordPress site inaccessible, and it may start showing Internal Server Error. That’s why it is important that you backup your .htaccess file before making any changes.

Below is basic .htaccess which lives in WP root folder

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Add the next lines just before # END WordPress

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^itz4u.in$
RewriteRule ^$ in.itz4u.in/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Your Final Code

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^itz4u.in$
RewriteRule ^$ in.itz4u.in/index.php [L,R=301]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try it and let you know

Comment: Requested other person to do modifications as I do not have rights